# Do you have to buy the books to get the 40k model rules?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The 8th edition of warhammer 40k was recently released and every model now has new rules.

In Age of Sigmar you can access models' rules for free either via the app or on the Games Workshop site.

Can you do the same with the new 40k or do you need to buy the new books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some packages are/will be released with 'data cards' which will give you the unit stats, and presumably the app will follow the same format as the AoS one.

You will still need the Rulebook, Indexes (in the interim) and Codex (when released) to play, or build your army, in anything more than the most basic manner.

Comment: From the sound of things, "new" models (those that did not exist at the time of creation of the index/codex) will have a dataslate in the box.  Existing models are all in the relevant index/codex.  I didn't realize an app was coming - do you have a link for that?

Comment: @Tal not handy, but an army builder was mentioned on the warhammer tv page

Comment: I don't think there has been anything official for 40k releasing an app or army builder to date. There is an app and the warscroll builder for Age of Sigmar, but nothing official for 40k from what I have seen.